# retrofit : cancellation of current request

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my app I have two buttons with edittext in recyclerview as below.

[image]

what i do is every time user clicks on plus or minus button, I am starting service. if user clicks plus button 100 times then it calls 100 times

```
startService(intent)
```

I am calling api through retrofit2 by call.enqueue.

I just want to restrict api calls. How can I do that?

**Edit**

I want only latest calls result. Therefore, I just want to cancel all other requests which are pending, and run only latest api call.

Comment: You can remove the onclicklistener on button when service starts, and set it again once it completes, you will need broadcast receiver to check when the service completes.

Comment: it is not clear what is the problem to `restrict api calls.`. Just determine conditions, on which you want to restrict, and implement `if` statement.

Comment: @AbhirojPanwar It is not good idea to stop user for adding items

Comment: @VladMatvienko Please check my edit

Comment: @Lalit Jadav I think this is where Rx introduced !!!

Comment: Which version of retrofit you are using? To get it done use Retrofit 2, it provide you an option to cancel the enqued call.                                        
    
// something happened, for example: user clicked cancel button
call.cancel();

Comment: ok, then do you know how to cancel a general call? Also I'd advise you to add an Apply button, so you call your API by pressing it only.

Comment: Each Time you press the button cancel the previous call first and enqueue the new one. this can be done for both your + and minus buttons. Furthermore rather than instantly hitting Api you can delay the hit. untill you dont find any subsequent action on button.

Comment: @LalitJadav I did not know of that condition. you can cancel your request in that case as you are using retrofit

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests

Comment: @Nisarg can you explain little bit more?

Comment: @AbhirojPanwar I am Call.enqueue and creating call on OnhandleIntent in Intentservice so i don't have access for that

Comment: @LalitJadav Use RxJava to handle multiple network calls ex. wait for each network call to return its response

Comment: You can use TimerTask for this to restrict API calls. Call API few seconds later onbutton clicked . Select time as suitable according to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hence, I got temporarry solution by giving api call number.
Whenever service calls I am assigning a variable 'ApiNumber' and in return I also got the same number.

ApiNumber is number of calls, it is increasing as api call increasing.

I only accept latest call response.

But, still I need to cancel api call.